# Loss of Per-diem - Employer has changed the rules

Tags: australia, cost-of-living

my employer (an international company) has decided that too much money is being spent on per-diems. I spend a lot of time away from home.
 Its been decided that if the meals etc are being taken care of by the client, we should get less- so, up until recently, we've been getting $60 per day.

Now, if the client pays for all 3 meals a day, we now get approx 80% less - making it less than $20 extra per day.

Are they able to do this - and if so, what are the implications? As far as I'm aware this is more of a living away from home allowance - not just a meal allowance.

Comment: Where are you and the company located?

Comment: Also, is the per-diem rate a part of your work contract or is it paid voluntary by your employer without being part of a formal agreement? Please answer this questions or yours will likely be closed as company-specific or general whining.

Comment: Just as aside, per-diem is in no way standard. In the UK, you can only generally claim for what you spend. So, if you don't have to buy any meals then you don't get to claim anything. Legally, we're only allowed £5 (yes, no missing zeroes) per day outside of those allowed expenses without incurring tax and that £5 still has to be accounted for! Just trying to add some perspective here as it doesn't seem too unreasonable to me

Comment: Yeah, no problems! I'm based in Australia - and up until now its been AU$60 without question, even if we spend $100/day
The PD is / was being paid over and above my normal salary

Answer (score 2):

Edit: OP commented that he lives in Australia. I am unaware of any labor laws in Australia regarding per diem compensation. My answer is based on my understanding of companies operating in the USA.

If you have an employment contract that specifically defines per diem amounts, then, no, the company cannot just change it arbitrarily. There may be a loophole clause that says the company can change the terms of the contract, though, so if this is the case, you may need to talk to a lawyer. But honestly, it'll cost you a lot of money to fight it, and what would be the point? Winning a suit against your current employer usually causes them to become your former employer rather quickly.

If there is no contractual per diem, and it's just a company policy, then yes, they can change their policies.

Comment: No worries, thanks Kent. Just a bit annoyed -- we've been using that extra $ to put away for our holiday / vacation.

Comment: @Wally A per diem is meant to simplify compensating you for reasonable expenses not as extra compensation for traveling. I think you'd have a stronger argument if you could show your per diem was not enough to cover your expenses. Even then it seems likely they would just offer to cover your true expenses.